# Val cannot be reassigned error even though I have already changed it to Var Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, android-drawable, var

*I am using Kotlin in IntelliJ.*

I have this short and simple bit of code

```
        val myLayoutView = v.findViewById(R.id.layout) as LinearLayout
        var myImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.image) as ImageView
        val myLabelView =v.findViewById(R.id.label) as TextView

        var app = getItem(position) as AppObject
        myLabelView.text = app.appName
        myImageView.drawable = app.appImage
```

Why in the WORLD is it telling me that on the line:

```
        myImageView.drawable = app.appImage
```

that "Val cannot be reassigned" Any instance of val has been COMPLETELY changed to var with respect to the variables mentioned.

I have already changed variables with the same name in other classes just to be sure and even changed every single variable in the class to var and I STILL get this error.

Does it have to do with the nature of drawable?

What am I missing or doing wrong to get this error and how do I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: [getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Kotlin Properties and Fields documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), a `val` property is a property with a getter, but no setter. A `var` property has both a getter and setter.

If you look at [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView), it has a `getDrawable()`, but no `setDrawable()` method. Kotlin automatically converts the getters in Java classes into properties, which is why you can use `myImageView.drawable` at all. However, since there is no `setDrawable()` method, that is a `val` property.

You'll need to use methods such as [`setImageDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) to set the image.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still very inexperienced, so just to clarify would this be the correct way of using setImageDrawable() you're speaking of:  <br/>`val myLayoutView = v.findViewById(R.id.layout) as LinearLayout  <br/>
        var myImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.image) as ImageView  <br/>
        val myLabelView =v.findViewById(R.id.label) as TextView  <br/>
  <br/>
        var app = getItem(position) as AppObject <br/> 
        myLabelView.text = app.appName  <br/>
        myImageView.setImageDrawable(app.appImage)`

Comment: Assuming `app.appImage` is a `Drawable`, yes, that's exactly correctly.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much Ian! Funny thing is before this iteration I was incorrectly using setImageDrawable() and was looking for alternate ways just to use it again haha.

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the meaning of var in that statement.

"var myImageView" means that the value of "var myImageView" can be changed. In other words, you can assign a different ImageView to it. It doesn't apply to the contents.

A better example:

```
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
var list2 = listOf(1, 2, 3)

list.add(5)            <----- Yes
list2.add(5)           <----- No

list = mutableListOf(3, 4, 5)   <----- No
list2 = mutableListOf(3, 4, 5)  <----- Yes
```

"list" is defined as val so you can't replace it. But since it is a mutable list you CAN change its contents

"list2" is defined as a var so you can replace it with another. However, it is a non-mutable list so its contents cannot be changed.